# Rest Sercvices Custom Status Code Response Serialization

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, rest

This is the ajax call I'm using to get the response from the rest services:

```
$.ajax({
    url: xxxxx,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(xxxx),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: asyncType,
    headers: { "ASP.NET_SessionId": apiReadCookie() },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        callback(data, paramters);
    },
    error: function (xhr, jqXHR, status, text) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log("The Current Response is " + jqXHR + " The Status is " + status + " The response is " + response);
        if (response) {
            console.log(response.error);
        } else {
        }
    }
});
```

The output I get from  this line:

```
            console.log("The Current Response is " + jqXHR + " The Status is " + status + " The response is " + response);
```

is : The Current Response is error The Status is Internal Server Error The response is [object Object]

How can I read the Response Object ? As you can see Json.parse is not working ,so is there something else ?

& is this is a correct method anyway or is there something better ?

Comment: if my answer solved your question don't forget to upvote and mark as top answer so that others will know if they face the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.dir( <object> );
```

will print the contents of an object to the console.

so:

```
console.log("Response is: ");
console.dir(response);
```

should do the trick